# rails 4.2 assets loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm playing with a rails 4.2 application and it seems like it loads all of my stylesheets for each and every page.

Is that true? How is it better than loading for each page only the relevant stylesheets?

On one hand, I know they'll all be minified when going to production, and it will reduce the total size and cache one CSS for the whole website.

On the other hand, page I might have some thin pages that will need no more than a few css lines to be rendered correctly that will get tones of files for no reason. It will also require me to be super strict and safe when choosing class names in order to have no collisions and unwanted overrides.

What about JS assets? It acts the same way?
(I guess the answer for image assets is "hell no!")

Comment: Yes it is true. Better if using turbo-links and caching. There are ways round it (see answers)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in development you'll see a lot of files (all of them) and in production they will be compiled and minified to a single file.

Once this file has been downloaded by the client it will be cached and wont need to make any further requests to load other stylesheet files on concurrent request (unless caching and turbolinks has been disabled). The downside is that the file size will be larger and make the initial load time slightly longer.

One problem as you point out is scoping. In my experience it's way better to always apply proper scopes when developing. And in rails using sass it's really easy to have nice and tidy css.

The same goes for javascript, but not for images as you pointed out.

That said. There are ways to work around this if desired, but more often than not I've realized that there are more pros than cons with a single file.

Edit: 
Oh, and if you're new to rails, beware that turbolinks might cause you some headaches in the beginning messing with page ready in js-files before you get the hang of it. But it's worth it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage and rationale for this is to reduce the amount of data that is sent to the client **after** the first page load. The first page load pulls down all the js/css (compiled into single files), but then this can be cached and reduces the amount on each subsequent page load.

**The following is purely theoretical, if at all possible, try and work with the defaults of one css/jss file**

If you absolutely do want to trim it down, then you can.  Your application.css manifest file (or js) probably includes a line such as:

```
//= require_tree .
```

which says, require everything in this directory. you could then split this down so application.css only requires everything in the application folder (absolutely need to know):

```
//=require_tree ./application
```

Then add additional manifest files, for example for an admin section, so that the admin styles/JS can be loaded only when needed in admin.js

```
//=require_tree ./admin
```

Then in your layout file you can do

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" 
= yield :additional_stylesheets
```

And where you want those additional styles you can add them.

```
- content_for :additional_stylesheets do 
   = stylesheet_link_tag "admin", media: "all" 
end
```

Note: this will cause issues if you're using turbolinks.
Note II: You may need to add these to the precompile list in application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['additional_manifests.css']
```

You could modify this workflow to not include any CSS at all to start with and only load what you need.